# Client-Server Checking for Two Connections

Tags: python, sockets, networking

After completing the whole clientside code for my pygame, I need to add a multiplayer function using client-server programming.

I have created a 'server' file:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
from _thread import *
import time

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host=socket.gethostname()
ip=socket.gethostbyname(host)
port=8000

connections=[]

print('Your local ip address is',ip)

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(2)

print('Waiting for a connection...')

def  threaded_client(connection):

    while True:
        data=connection.recv(2048) #anything we receive
        if not data:
            break        

    connection.close()


while True:
    connection,address=s.accept()
    print(address,'has connected to server hosted at port',address[1])
    connections.append(address)
    print(connections)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(connection,))
```

In my game, the user is prompted to enter an IP address. On two different PCs on the same network, I put in the same IP, and the server printed that both of the IPs were connected to the server.

On the host's client, I want for them to be shown a screen that says 'waiting for incoming connections'. I have coded this screen, but am unsure how to send the information to the clients so that it displays that when there are less than 2 connections to the server (as the game is a 1v1).

In my main file:

```
 if click[0]==1 and action=='classselection':

            host=socket.gethostname()
            ip=socket.gethostbyname(host)

            if address==ip:
                ishost=True

            else:
                ishost=False

            try:
                s=socket.socket()
                address=address
                port=8000
                connectionwaitingmenu()

                while True:
                    s.connect((address,port))
                    print('The connection is still established.')

            except:
                connectionmenu(True)
```

How would I send the message from the server with information of how many items are connected to the client, and how would the client receive it?